# Thread wait on file input pattern

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, file-io, input

What's the normal pattern for a thread to wait for file input in C# when it reaches end of file and 
 needs to wait. Any particularly way of coding it, which is neat and elegant.

Thanks.
 Bob.

Comment: Please provide some more information about what you 're trying to do, and how.

Comment: Essentially i'm looking for a way to block (possibly with a timeout) until their is something available in a file to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a pattern but the `FileSystemWatcher` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) might come in handy.

Comment: I've used that in the past and wrong place/wrong time. I have a threaded reader, reading the file. Its opened for shared reading and writing.

Comment: Its seems FileSystemWatcher is a pretty decent kernel file change event listener, but polling times are a bit uncertain. Worth using in combination with FileInfo for double check on file size change.

Answer (score 1):

I will be interested in seeing what the other answers are. I have not found an elegant solution. Here is what I have done in the past.

1. Have the reader try to open the file exclusively. This will fail if the file is open elsewhere.
2. Have a retry loop....sleep X milliseconds...retry Y times. Usually, I pull X & Y out into a configuration file.

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: That's the approach I use. The other advantage it offers is that it forces you to wait until the file writer is done; important if it's a big file coming over a slow link. But since the OP wants shared read/write, you poll for bytecount > 0 from the last valid position. It's elegant enough.